# How does this App Engine Ndb syntax work?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Guido van Rossum's `Ndb` library for Google App Engine has a [syntax for queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop) that I find curious. Suppose you wanted to find all happy users, you would write this query:

```
User.query(User.happy == True)
```

I read that as:

- A function call of the `query` method of the `User` class, which inherits from `ndb.Model`. Fine so far.
- The one argument of the function call is an expression doing a boolean comparison between a class property, `User.happy`, and a value, `True`.

I would expect the expression to evaluate to `False` (much as `dict.keys == True` would), so the above should be equivalent to:

```
User.query(False)
```

How does Ndb do anything intelligent with that? What python magic am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing python magic methods.

```
__eq__(self, other)
```

> Defines behavior for the equality operator, ==.

Good guide about this could be found [here](http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#comparisons).

Comment: Ok, that's clever. Thanks! I still find it odd-looking. In particular, it seems to run afoul of PEP 8, "Don't compare boolean values to True or False using ==". I understand that you're saying this isn't *really* a boolean comparison. Still, my brain's syntax checker hiccups every time.

Comment: Yes, I had to turn E711 & E712 off due to this syntax.